# Blank Webpage Dialog on Webpart connection configuration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, web-part-connection

When configuring connection for Webpart in Sharepoint 2013 i've got a blank webpage dialog, I don't know what causes it ? here's screenshots:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your secure store connection is not configured properly

Comment: Can you tell me how to properly configure it please?